# While refactoring this Common Lisp code snippet, how to succesfully remove the cond clause wrapping a handler-case (error handling) situation?

Tags: error-handling, refactoring, common-lisp

I am using SBCL, Emacs, Slime, and Dexador (a library for HTTP requests). I have this function **that works**:

```lisp
(defun old-handle-response-and-status (final-url method &optional user-content)
  (let ((status-code)
        (response))
    (cond ((equal method "get")
           (multiple-value-bind (bresponse bstatus-code)
               (handler-case (dex:get final-url)
                 (dex:http-request-bad-request ()
                   (values nil
                           "The server returned a failed request of 400 (bad request) status."))
                 (dex:http-request-failed (e)
                   (values nil
                           (format nil "The server returned a failed request of ~a status." (dex:response-status e)))))
             (list (setf response bresponse)
                   (setf status-code bstatus-code))))
          ((equal method "post")
           (multiple-value-bind (bresponse bstatus-code)
               (handler-case (dex:post final-url
                                       :content user-content)
                 (dex:http-request-bad-request ()
                   (values nil
                           "The server returned a failed request of 400 (bad request) status."))
                 (dex:http-request-failed (e)
                   (values nil
                           (format nil "The server returned a failed request of ~a status." (dex:response-status e)))))
             (list (setf response bresponse)
                   (setf status-code bstatus-code)))))))
```

It works for `GET`, `POST`, and the **error handling** works **as expected** when a HTTP request faces errors. The iconic examples to show it working are:

```lisp
CL-USER> (old-handle-response-and-status "http://www.paulgraham.com" "get")

("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\">
<html>
(big HTML omitted)
</html>"
 200)

CL-USER> (old-handle-response-and-status "https://httpbin.org/post" "post" '(("name" . "pedro")))
("{
medium JSON omitted
}
"
 200)

CL-USER> (old-handle-response-and-status "https://httpstat.us/409" "get")
(NIL "The server returned a failed request of 409 status.")
```

Ok. While refactoring this code, I was trying to remove the `cond` clause. Thus I did a new shorter version:

```lisp
(defun new-handle-response-and-status (method-call)
  (let ((status-code)
        (response))
    (multiple-value-bind (bresponse bstatus-code)
        (handler-case method-call
          (dex:http-request-bad-request ()
            (values nil
                    "The server returned a failed request of 400 (bad request) status."))
          (dex:http-request-failed (e)
            (values nil
                    (format nil "The server returned a failed request of ~a status." (dex:response-status e)))))
      (list (setf response bresponse)
            (setf status-code bstatus-code)))))
```

It **majorly works**, but *only when the request is successful*:

```lisp
CL-USER> (new-handle-response-and-status (dex:get "http://www.paulgraham.com"))
("
HTML omitted
</html>"
 NIL)

CL-USER> (new-handle-response-and-status (dex:post "https://httpbin.org/post" :content '(("name" . "pedro"))))
("{
medium JSON omitted
}
"
 NIL)
```

When the request is a failed HTTP request, the **refactoring does not** work as expected!
When calling:

```lisp
CL-USER> (new-handle-response-and-status (dex:get "https://httpstat.us/409"))
```

The Slime Debugger throws:

```lisp
An HTTP request to "https://httpstat.us/409" returned 409 conflict.
```

I was expecting:

```lisp
(NIL "The server returned a failed request of 409 status.")
```

I tried tweaking the input to be a quoted s-expression and inserting an `eval`:

```lisp
(defun new-handle-response-and-status (method-call)
  (let ((status-code)
        (response))
    (multiple-value-bind (bresponse bstatus-code)
        (handler-case (eval method-call)
          (dex:http-request-bad-request ()
            (values nil
                    "The server returned a failed request of 400 (bad request) status."))
          (dex:http-request-failed (e)
            (values nil
                    (format nil "The server returned a failed request of ~a status." (dex:response-status e)))))
      (list (setf response bresponse)
            (setf status-code bstatus-code)))))
```

It works:

```lisp
CL-USER> (new-handle-response-and-status '(dex:get "https://httpstat.us/409"))
(NIL "The server returned a failed request of 409 status.")
```

But, it feels as a bad practice - not really compatible with a refactoring effort. Is there a way to fix this without using `eval`?

Maybe using `funcall`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `dex:get` or `dex:post` before invoking the function, so the handler binding is not in effect.

You need to pass a function that calls it, and then call that function.

```
(defun new-handle-response-and-status (method-call)
  (let ((status-code)
        (response))
    (multiple-value-bind (bresponse bstatus-code)
        (handler-case (funcall method-call)
          (dex:http-request-bad-request ()
            (values nil
                    "The server returned a failed request of 400 (bad request) status."))
          (dex:http-request-failed (e)
            (values nil
                    (format nil "The server returned a failed request of ~a status." (dex:response-status e)))))
      (list (setf response bresponse)
            (setf status-code bstatus-code)))))

(new-handle-response-and-status (lambda () (dex:get "https://httpstat.us/409")))
```

Or you could convert it to a macro:

```
(defmacro new-handle-response-and-status (method-call)
  `(let ((status-code)
         (response))
     (multiple-value-bind (bresponse bstatus-code)
         (handler-case ,method-call
           (dex:http-request-bad-request ()
                                         (values nil
                                                 "The server returned a failed request of 400 (bad request) status."))
           (dex:http-request-failed (e)
                                    (values nil
                                            (format nil "The server returned a failed request of ~a status." (dex:response-status e)))))
       (list (setf response bresponse)
             (setf status-code bstatus-code)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember evaluation rules.

```
CL-USER 36 > (defun foo (a)
               (print 'foo1)
               a    
               (print 'foo2)
               'return-value)
FOO

CL-USER 37 > (foo (print 'bar1))

BAR1 
FOO1 
FOO2 
RETURN-VALUE
```

`(print 'bar1)` is evaluated **outside** of `foo`.